# What is a word for someone who loves to experience?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, phrases

What is a word for someone who loves to experience? A philomath is someone who loves to learn. Wanderlust describes a strong desire to travel. In that vein, is there a word for someone who seeks to experience things: boat rides, a circus performance, ice cream cones at the beach, attending a concert. In this context, a gift of experience would be preferred to an object or possession - for example, tickets to a baseball game rather than a baseball jersey.

Comment: Extroverted, perhaps?

Comment: Experientialist is an proponent of experientialism, the philosophical theory that experience is the source of knowledge

Comment: Perhaps a "thrill seeker"?

Comment: Geoffrey Chaucer would say *liver*, but that word has a different connotation now.

Comment: *Adventurer? Bon viveur? Hedonist?* Or the opposite, *outgoing* or *sociable*? *Restless? Ants in his pants?*

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are looking for "novelty seeker"? In the [psychological sense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novelty_seeking), the meaning might be a bit strong, but, generally, someone who enjoys having new/different/a range of experiences could be said to seek novelty. I certainly use the term of myself. "Thrill seeker", of course, would work if the types of experiences are adrenaline inducing.

And I just found [this](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/neophilia):

> Definition of NEOPHILIA: love of or enthusiasm for what is new or
>   novel

So "neophile" would also work.